QT QODBC driver not loaded MacOS
I encountered a problem on my MacBook. I’m working on a project using Qt, which is supposed to interact with a local MS SQL Server database. The database is deployed via Docker with the address localhost:1433. When attempting to connect, I get the following error:
qt.sql.qsqldatabase: QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
qt.sql.qsqldatabase: QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL QMIMER
true

Here is my connection code:
void login::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    //db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="+ui->lineEdit->text()+";DATABASE="+ui->lineEdit_2->text()+";");
    //db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER="
    //+ ui->lineEdit->text() + ";DATABASE=" + ui->lineEdit_2->text() + ";TrustServerCertificate=Yes;");

    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setPort(1433);
    db.setUserName("sa");
    db.setPassword("DB_Password");
    db.setDatabaseName("master");

    qDebug() << db.isDriverAvailable("QODBC");

    //db.setUserName(ui->label_3->text());
    //db.setPassword(ui->lineEdit_4->text());

    if (db.open()) {
        mes->setText("Success!");
    } else {
        mes->setText("Error");
    }

    mes->show();
}

The driver has been downloaded, but Qt cannot load it.
Reinstall QT and driver, include driver in path
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" export ODBCINI=/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini 
export ODBCINSTINI=/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini 
source ~/.zshrc 

cd /path/to/Qt/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc 
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/opt/homebrew/include" "LIBS+=-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lodbc" 
make 
cp libqsqlodbc.dylib /path/to/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/

odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.12
DRIVERS............: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/artempervyh/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

and cat /opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
UsageCount=2


How did you install the driver? Please add details about how you included the driver in the project and any relevant building commands you did.

Please don't add details in comments (especially if they're code), instead [edit] the question and update it accordingly.

Do you have multiple versions of Qt installed? Is it possible you're using the wrong version of qmake to build the driver for the version of Qt you're trying to use?

What's the console output from odbcinst -j. And also from cat /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini?

The output for commands has been added to the question.
I have only one version of Qt installed, downloaded from the official website. I doubt the problem is related to the version of qmake, as I tried creating a simple project with a connection using CMake and faced the same issue.
